# Combining multiple functions through loops and parameters

Tags: python, csv

*UPDATE* My question has been fully answered, I have applied it to my program using jarmod's answer, and although the code looks neater, it has not effected the speed of (when my graph appears( i plot this data using matplotlib) I am a a little confused on why my program runs slowly and how I can increase the speed ( takes about 30 seconds and I know this portion of the code is slowing it down) I have shown my real code in the second block of code. Also, the speed is strongly determined by the Range I set, with a short range it is quiet fast

I have this sample code here that shows my calculation needed to conduct forecasting and extracting values. I use the for loops to run through a specific range of CSV files that I labeled 1-100. I return numbers for each month (1-12) to get the forecasting average for a forecast for a given amount of month.

My full code includes 12 functions for a full year forecast but I feel the code is inefficient because the functions are very similar except for one number and reading the csv file so many times slows the program.

Is there a way I can combine these functions and perhaps add another parameter to make it run so. The biggest concern I had was that it would be hard to return separate numbers and categorize them. In other words, I would like to ideally only have one function for all 12 month accuracy predictions and the way I can possibly see how to do that would to add another parameter and another loop series, but have no idea how to go about that or if it is possible. Essentially, I would like to store all the values of onemonthaccuracy ( which goes into the file before the current file and compares the predicted value for the date associated with the currentfile) and then store all the values of twomonthaccurary and so on... so I can later use these variables for graphing and other purposes

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

def onemonthaccuracy(basefilenumber):
    basefileread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber)+'.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    basefilevalue = basefileread.loc[basefileread['Customer'].str.contains('Customer A', na=False), 'Jun-16\nQty'] 

    onemonthread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber-1)+'.csv', encoding='latin-1')
    onemonthvalue = onemonthread.loc[onemonthread['Customer'].str.contains('Customer A', na=False),'Jun-16\nQty']   

    onetotal = int(onemonthvalue)/int(basefilevalue)   

    return onetotal


def twomonthaccuracy(basefilenumber):
    basefileread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber)+'.csv', encoding='Latin-1')
    basefilevalue = basefileread.loc[basefileread['Customer'].str.contains('Customer A', na=False), 'Jun-16\nQty']

    twomonthread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber-2)+'.csv', encoding = 'Latin-1')
    twomonthvalue = twomonthread.loc[twomonthread['Customer'].str.contains('Customer A', na=False), 'Jun-16\nQty']

    twototal = int(twomonthvalue)/int(basefilevalue)    

    return twototal


onetotal = 0
twototal = 0
onetotallist = []
twototallist = []


for basefilenumber in range(24,36):
    onetotal += onemonthaccuracy(basefilenumber)
    twototal +=twomonthaccuracy(basefilenumber)
    onetotallist.append(onemonthaccuracy(i)) 
    twototallist.append(twomonthaccuracy(i))

onetotalpermonth = onetotal/12
twototalpermonth = twototal/12   
x = [1,2]
y = [onetotalpermonth, twototalpermonth]
z = [1,2]
w = [(onetotallist),(twototallist)]

for ze, we in zip(z, w):
    plt.scatter([ze] * len(we), we, marker='D', s=5)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This is the real block of code I am using in my program, perhaps something is slowing it down that I am unaware of?

```
#other parts of code 
#StartRange = yearvalue+Value
#EndRange = endValue + endyearvalue
#Range = EndRange - StartRange
# Department
#more code.... 

def nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber, n):
    basefileread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber)+'.csv', encoding='Latin-1')
    baseheader = getfileheader(basefilenumber)
    basefilevalue = basefileread.loc[basefileread['Customer'].str.contains(Department, na=False), baseheader]

    nmonthread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber-n)+'.csv', encoding = 'Latin-1')
    nmonthvalue = nmonthread.loc[nmonthread['Customer'].str.contains(Department, na=False), baseheader]

    return (1-(int(basefilevalue)/int(nmonthvalue))+1) if int(nmonthvalue) > int(basefilevalue) else int(nmonthvalue)/int(basefilevalue)  

N = 13
total = [0] * N
total_by_month_list  = [[] for _ in range(N)]
for basefilenumber in range(int(StartRange),int(EndRange)):
    for n in range(N):
    total[n] += nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber, n)
    total_by_month_list[n].append(nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber,n)) 

onetotal=total[1]/ Range
twototal=total[2]/ Range
threetotal=total[3]/ Range
fourtotal=total[4]/ Range
fivetotal=total[5]/ Range #... all the way to 12 

onetotallist=total_by_month_list[1]
twototallist=total_by_month_list[2]
threetotallist=total_by_month_list[3]
fourtotallist=total_by_month_list[4]
fivetotallist=total_by_month_list[5] #... all the way to 12 
# alot more code after this
```

Comment: The sole difference is the -1/-2 offset, yes? Why not pass that value as a parameter?

Comment: @jarmod yes that is the difference, however I still want to store everything that is -1 into one variable and everything with -2 in another, so I was not sure exactly how I would be able to store the variables correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber, n):
    basefileread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber)+'.csv', encoding='Latin-1')
    basefilevalue = basefileread.loc[basefileread['Customer'].str.contains('Lam DepT', na=False), 'Jun-16\nQty']

    nmonthread = pd.read_csv(str(basefilenumber-n)+'.csv', encoding = 'Latin-1')
    nmonthvalue = nmonthread.loc[nmonthread['Customer'].str.contains('Lam DepT', na=False), 'Jun-16\nQty']

    return int(nmonthvalue)/int(basefilevalue)    

N = 2
total_by_month = [0] * N
total_aggregate = 0

for basefilenumber in range(20,30):
    for n in range(N):
        a = nmonthaccuracy(basefilenumber, n)
        total_by_month[n] += a
        total_aggregate += a
```

In case you are wondering what the following  code does:

```
N = 2
total_by_month = [0] * N
```

It sets `N` to the number of months desired (2, but you could make it 12 or another value) and it then creates a `total_by_month` array that can store N results, one per month. It then initializes `total_by_month` to all zeroes (`N` zeroes) so that each of the `N` monthly totals starts at zero.

Comment: Thank you for this, that looks good. I have updated my question to show that I need to use my return value( for the specific months ) and graph them. How do I access these specific variables for use such as graphing? This was the main reason why this question puzzled me, because I was unsure if I would be able to use the variables specifically like this

Comment: I believe that this method totals up all the data vs categorizing them with certain months, unless I am mistaken

Comment: It accumulates month n's totals in total[n].

Comment: Oh sweet, this does work, thanks alot! I have updated my question to show that I will also need to append specific values and all of that, will this code structure allow me to do that as well ( I can figure that portion for myself, I just want to see if I am going in the right direction)

Comment: Or if you would be able to explain the N=2; and Total = [0] * N portion of the code, I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: I've added an explanation to my answer. If you have additional questions, beyond the scope of how to use arrays and loops to do things repetitively, then it's worth starting up a new, standalone question that's focused on the new problem.

Comment: Hi, I have fully integrated this code into my program and it does not increase the speed of the program at all, infact made it a little slower. It takes about 30 seconds ( for my graph to appear when i create a graph using this data) any idea of why it takes so long? Any advice would be greatly apprenticed

Comment: Fewer lines of code does not necessarily equate to faster code, particularly when you're replacing N sequential invocations of, essentially, the same lines of code with a for loop that simply iterates over the equivalent code N times. The code, overall, still needs to do the same amount of work. Fewer lines of code equates to fewer bugs (usually) and, in this case, more extensible and modular code. It might also be faster, but only if it's doing less work.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I made the assumption that my program was doing unnecessary work when I suppose it was not. However, what is baffling is that no matter what Range I set, this new method will be 2 seconds slower than the old way. Is there some sort of build up or something that may be causing this ?

Comment: Your questions continue to morph into new questions. It is better to create a new post with *a minimal* example that exhibits the problem you are trying to solve. Also, related to your current code, declaring threetotal, fourtotal, fivetotal etc. is not the correct thing to do. Programming languages have arrays for this. Imagine that you wanted to calculate up to 1 million totals. Would you want to write a million lines of code going all the way up to milliontotal?